# Term-document matrix or document-term matrix for principal component analysis?

Tags: r, pca, lda

I'm engaging in text analysis and have a corpus in which I would like to achieve dimensionality reduction.

I understand that principal component analysis is the standard way to do this.

After getting a reasonable number of dimensions, I hope to apply Latent Dirichelet Allocation in order to classify the documents.

In reading the literature, I see that some sources recommend using a document-term matrix (dtm, documents as rows, terms as columns) for the PCA, while others recommend using a term-document matrix (tdm, terms as rows, documents as columns).

I have about 2400 documents and 478,000 terms.

Is it ok to conduct PCA on a tdm, then obtain K, with which I can undertake LDA?

Comment: This question should be moved to the `stats` stackexchange.

Comment: For most any modeling (not just text classification), each row is an observation and each column is a feature. If you are classifying documents based on their terms, then you are treating each document as an observation and the terms in the document as features. So you should have documents in your rows and terms as columns.